# No reply for ping command. What does this mean?

Tags: networking, ping

I am testing the availability of nodes in a netwok. For that I use ping command and see whether that machine responds back.

However, if a machine is not reachable ping should show me that that "Destination host not reachable". But if it can, it should return back with the response message. But there is no message  which is being received!

What does this imply? - That ping is not enabled on that particular machine but reachable on the network ?

Comment: You have to make sure the end point is set to answer to ping requests. What kind of end points do you have?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ping is not the best tool to be used to test the availability of a remote network.  Although ping can tell you that a network is reachable and send you response times, the lack of that information  does not imply that the network is down.  As the saying goes, absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Open your browser and go to yahoo.com and intel.com.  Both come up right?
Try pinging Yahoo `ping yahoo.com` then try pinging Intel `ping intel.com`  Intel doesnt return any ping results.  Intel probably disabled ping response for security reasons, like denying ping flooding.

Another issue with ping is that people often misinterpret the results.  If you are getting a long response time, people often blame the endpoint.  If you are in Windows, type `pathping yahoo.com` and you will see a combination of traceroute and ping, which gives much better information.

Comment: `Ping is not the best tool to be used to test the availability of a remote network.` then can you suggest some other alternative tools to detect availability ?

Comment: @VikasGoel Well, if there was a sure thing, we would all be using it.  Ping is often blocked to prevent ping flooding.  The best way to test a remote server is to try to use the service it is serving.  Ping can *only* tell you if something is up, it cant tell you something is down (not without more information).

Answer (score 5):

It means that your ICMP packet (ping) was silently discarded with no response sent. That might happen for several reasons:

- Ping is disabled on router or (more likely) end point.
- Network is congested or misconfigured

Comment: "Pinging" is enabled in my case. Wireshark also sees the ping request coming. But there is no responses!

Answer (score 5):

if your on a linux machine, you could use [nmap](https://nmap.org/) instead

```
nmap -sP 192.168.x.0/24
```

For windows, [netscanner.exe](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) is an excellent tool (with a "live display" functionality that shows you host come and go in real time)

-- EDIT --

Since netscanner is not freeware anymore, but trialware (only the first 10 results will be shown), I went looking for alternatives and I came across this free product:
https://www.mitec.cz/netscan.html

This website hosts many other useful related network tools

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that ping is a connection like any other. It must be enabled in the firewall to be accepted and there must be service that listens and sends reply.
In most cases, ping does not work because of firewall settings.
Also do not forget that normally ping returns **Connection timeout.**. **Destination host not reachable.** is returned when the IP is not within the network.

Comment: "Do not forget that ping connection like any other." Yes and no. Typical traffic uses TCP or UDP over IP. `ping` uses the `ICMP` protocol which is a different beast altogether.